# Only show element when scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll

I just want the text to show when scrolling and hide when not scrolling. I'm new to jQuery. There's got to be a way to do it.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("document").on("scroll" () {
    $(".infoa").toggleClass("infob");
  });
});
```

```css
.infoa {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20%;
  right: 50px;
}

.infob {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="infoa">
  <h1>Thanks!</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly there's a couple of syntax issues in your code. You need a `,` between `'scroll'` and the function body, and `$('document')` should be `$(document)`, as it's an object not a selector in the DOM.

With regard to the actual problem, the `scroll` event fires (roughly) once per pixel scrolled. Therefore your current logic is toggling the class each time that happens, which can result in the class being left on the element.

To correct this behaviour you can add the class when scrolling occurs, and then use a timeout to remove the class after scrolling has ended. the 50ms delay I used in the example below can be tweaked as necessary for your use case.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let timeout;
  let $infoa = $('.infoa');

  $(document).on("scroll", () => {
    $infoa.addClass("infob");
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => $infoa.removeClass('infob'), 50);
  });
});
```

```css
html, body { height: 1000px; } /* just for this demo to cause a scrollbar to appear */

.infoa {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20%;
  right: 50px;
}

.infob {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="infoa">
  <h1>Thanks!</h1>
</div>
```